# how do i turn this input name to the correct label format

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have this name on my input

```
driver_application[company_name]
```

and i need to create the label name to be

```
driver_application_company_name
```

Here is my jquery to get the input

```
$(".company_name").attr("name")
```

will return

```
driver_application[company_name]
```

how do i convert it to the right format with javascript or jquery ...maybe regex

Comment: right format for what? - disregard... reread it and understand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Javascript method [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
var source = 'driver_application[company_name]';
var formatted = source.replace('[', '_').replace(']', '');
console.log(formatted); //prints driver_application_company_name
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
'driver_application[company_name]'.replace('[', '_').replace(']', '');
```

Answer (score 1):

Get name from exisitng input to be used for some other elemetnt

```
var labelName=$(".company_name").attr("name").replace('[','_').replace(']','');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(".company_name").attr("name","driver_application_company_name")
```

http://api.jquery.com/attr/